# Operation not allowed on string vector in H2o package

Tags: r, random-forest, h2o

I get the following error when I run a random forest model using H2o package.

> Error: DistributedException from localhost/127.0.0.1:54321, caused by
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Operation not allowed on string
>   vector.

The code I ran was as follows:-

```
fit = h2o.randomForest(x = indep, y = dep, training_frame = QCAnalysis_sub_h2o, seed = 1234, ntrees = 500, mtries = 3, max_depth = 50)
```

Kindly clarify on the error.

Comment: Please add some example data, probably one of your columns is a character vector which is not allowed as input

Answer (score 3):

Make sure that `class(QCAnalysis_sub_h2o)` is "H2OFrame" and that your `indep` vector doesn't contain any columns that are strings.  Also, note that when converting an R data.frame to an H2O Frame using `as.h2o()`, it preserves the column types, so it won't automatically convert any string columns into factors.  You will need to do that automatically using the `as.factor()` function on each column (e.g. `df[,"mycol"] <- as.factor(df[,"mycol"]`).  You can do this on your R data.frame before you copy over to H2O, or you can fix the columns once they are in the H2O Frame.

If you read in a CSV file from disk directly into H2O using the `h2o.importFile()` command, it will turn any column containing strings into factors by default, so I assume that you probably copied this frame over from R.

Comment: For non-numeric (in other words, categorical) data, yes, H2O algos only allow factor columns, but not string/character columns.

Comment: @ErinLeDell this manual transformation seems only needed for the target column? 'auto' only fixes input variables? documentation isn't clear https://h2o-release.s3.amazonaws.com/h2o/rel-ueno/2/docs-website/h2o-docs/data-science/algo-params/categorical_encoding.html

Comment: All categorical columns must be factors (includes features and response).  The `categorical_encoding` option encodes factors into another representation under the hood, but it must be a factor to start with.

Answer (score 0):

Some sample codes:

```
QCAnalysis_sub_h2o <- h2o.importFile(path = normalizePath("QCAnalysis_sub_h2o.csv"),header=T)
```

(if not, specify the dataframe with as.data.frame )

x and y should state the columns you want h2o.randomforest to read